# Subdomain redirection, URL Masking

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, httpd.conf

My issue is simple but I can't seem to find the solution.

I have a domain **www.domain.com** that has subdomains.

www.domain.com 's document root is `/home/domain/public_html`

Subdomains (excluding www) need to be redirected to example.com
i.e. abc.domain com need to be redirected to `/home/example/public_html`

Also, the url needs to be retained. i.e. `abc.domain.com` need to show in the address bar.

**What I have done till now**
I have maintained in httpd.conf the following entry under

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)domain.com$
  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%1example.com$0
```

However, the url is changing to abc.example.com and www.domain.com is being redirected to www.example.com too.

Please suggest the best way to resolve this.

**Virtual Hosts configuration**, without Rewrite rules,

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName domain.com
      ServerAlias *.domain.com www.domain.com
      DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html
      UseCanonicalName Off
      ## User abc # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
      UserDir enabled abc
      <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
          <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
             SuexecUserGroup abc abc
          </IfModule>
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
          RMode config
          RUidGid abc abc
      </IfModule>
      <IfModule itk.c>
          AssignUserID abc abc
      </IfModule>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I assume you meant `/home/domain/public_html` in both cases in your question, and not `/home/example/public_html` for the subdomain.

Comment: No I meant /home/example/public_html for the subdomain. Subdomains need to be redirected & masked too.

Comment: I think you are using confusing terms here, which makes it hard to understand your goal. Redirect is when user's browser is instructed to load another URL, for example, loading `http://www.example.com/test`, the server sends a `301` redirect telling browser to load `http://www.example.com/another` URL instead. Another thing is changing the document root for a domain on the webserver. Please try to re-phrase your question so that your goal is more clearly stated. Please include also your virtual host configuration from your webserver.

Comment: Thanks. It's my lack of knowledge on the correct terminology that's confusing. Let me try again. I want the document root of **www.domain.com** to be `/home/domain/public_html`. For any other subdomain (e.g. **abc.domain.com**), the document root should be `/home/example/public_html`. Also, **the URL should be retained** i.e. abc.domain.com should not get converted to abc.example.com.

Comment: And the virtual host(s) configuration?

Comment: Included the configuration in the main question.

Comment: I updated my answer based on the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `RewriteRule` directive here. You need to make a virtual host for the subdomain, and then assign the same document root as the main domain to that subdomain.

`RewriteRule` is used when you need to redirect the users' browsers to new URLs, and the new URL always shows up in browsers' URL field.

So, you should remove the `RewriteRule` and related directives, and use this virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html
  UseCanonicalName Off
  ## User abc # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  UserDir enabled abc
  <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
      <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
         SuexecUserGroup abc abc
      </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
      RMode config
      RUidGid abc abc
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule itk.c>
      AssignUserID abc abc
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName other.domain.com
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
  UseCanonicalName Off
  ## User abc # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  UserDir enabled abc
  <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
      <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
         SuexecUserGroup abc abc
      </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
      RMode config
      RUidGid abc abc
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule itk.c>
      AssignUserID abc abc
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

For the second virtual host, you can use any non-existing sub-domain name for the `ServerName` directive. However, you need a non-wildcard `ServerName` directive there, since wildcards are allowed only in `ServerAlias` directive.

The trick here is that the first `VirtualHost` block is used for `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`, since Apache uses the first matching `VirtualHost` block. There the document root is set to `/home/domain/public_html`.

The second `VirtualHost` block is used for all other matching domains and there the document root is `/home/example/public_html`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can't return your great favour but will surely pay it forward :)

Comment: Oh ok. What to do with simply **domain.com** that should be treated as www.domain.com too? Currently with this virtual host configuration it's being directed to example.com.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `domain.com` to the `ServerAlias` line in the first virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^w]*).domain.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%1.example.com$0
```

The regular expression will now match any hostname other than a string of w's. (This would need to be modified if you ever needed w.domain.com, ww.domain.com, wwww.domain.com, etc. to work.)

Comment: Thanks for the www exclusion rule. But the subdomain redirection masking is not working. abc.domain.com is getting transformed to abc.example.com.